# struggling to print arrays

Tags: java, arrays

so, I'm trying to print multidimensional arrays with print statements

```
output of row 0: 2 3 6 8 10 12 14 16,
output of row 1:4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 
and output of row 2: 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    int [][] array = {{2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16},{4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18},{6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20}};

      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
      }    
}
```

Comment: Unclear what problem you are having. Are you missing a `System.out.println();` after the inner loop?

Comment: And your issue is?

Comment: Simpler, but not with exactly the same output: `Arrays.asList(array).forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));`

Comment: Please, are you stating the *observed* output or the output *that you want* in your question? Please also state the other so we can know what the difference and therefore what your issue is.

Comment: Please be more clear on what exactly are you asking for ? With the above question it becomes absolute nightmare to `guess` what you could probably be asking !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this and get your output

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = {{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16}, {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18}, {6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}};
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("output of row " + i + ": ");
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: how can I add print statements to this code, eg. row 0 output is  2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16 and row 1 is 4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18.

Comment: @sammy1180 Its the same code. Only difference is I have added System.out.print("output of row " + i + ": "); before your inner loop and added System.out.println(); after your inner loop

Answer (score 3):

Note that the difference between `print` and `println`:

**println(String x):**

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The
>   line separator string is defined by the system property
>   line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character
>   ('\n').

**print(String s):**

> Prints a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is
>   printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes
>   according to the platform's default character encoding, and these
>   bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

So `println` add an addtional `line separator` for you compared with `print`

**Reference:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to handle this. I suggest for-each loop to print the arrays as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = {{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16}, {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18}, {6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}};
    int i=1;
    for (int[] row : array)
    {
        System.out.println("output of row " +i +Arrays.toString(row));
        i++;
    }
}
}
```

---

Comment: @OleV.V.  Thanks for your suggestion. Really appreciate it.